# $ yarn install leads to Cannot find module yarn-berry.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

New to react and am having trouble with the yarn install command where i get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/MacPro/Desktop/Developer/React/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47   code:'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []
```

Anything related to the yarn function returns this error. Have tried uninstalling and re-installing through homebrew but always results in this. npm install -g yarn says it is updated and installed as well.

Any help?

Also, it worked fine a few weeks ago.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it very likely means that your application is not running with the PnP resolver, meaning that your require calls won’t be able to load files from your dependencies (since the node_modules needed for the regular Node resolution won’t have been generated). Make sure to either run your code using NODE_OPTIONS="--require /path/to/.pnp.js" or to call it using yarn node.

Comment: Try setting `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`

Comment: Neither of these have worked unfortunately. Even the yarn version command leads to this error and so does every other command using yarn. I can always use npm but this is driving me up a wall.

Answer (score 28):

Ok so I guess like me you did not read the whole Yarn documentation.
To get out of this:

1. Remove the `.yarnrc.yml` file in your project
2. Configure again Yarn 2: `yarn set version berry`
3. Configure your `.gitignore` file according to Yarn documentation: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored

If like me, you do not want to commit 1000+ dependency files to your repository, add these lines to your `.gitignore` file:

```
.yarn/*
!.yarn/patches
!.yarn/releases
!.yarn/plugins
!.yarn/sdks
!.yarn/versions
.pnp.*
```

After that, your commit should contain:

- the updated `.yarnrc.yml` file (or none if the file did not change)
- the `.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.js` file (maybe it is named otherwise like `yarn-berry.cjs`, the important thing is that this file matches what is contained in your `.yarnrc.yml` file)

Comment: Or you may be like me and failed to remove `/.yarn/` elsewhere in your `.gitignore` file. I was actually surprised this is how `.gitignore` works, which is probably why I didn't remove it in the first place.

Comment: If you are experiencing this issue, *this* is the first answer you should look at and try. It will likely fix your problem and is the most proper way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, deleting .yarnrc.yml and creating a new one with yarn set version berry worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I think that you tried to update your version of Yarn to version 2 by vaguely following (as I did) the tutorial here :https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration

Maybe you realised you did not like Yarn 2 (no node_modules folder anymore... seriously Yarn?), uninstalled it, deleted different files manually, and now end up with this error (at least it was my case).

You are now trying to make a clean install of Yarn 1 because you still prefer it to npm (as I do) and you end up getting those crazy errors telling Yarn is looking form something mentioning some Berry thing you can't find, this error :

```
   node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
          throw err;
          ^
        
        Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Username/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs'
```

You have to first make a complete uninstall of Yarn.
Based on what you used to install it :

```
npm uninstall -g yarn
```

or

```
brew uninstall yarn
```

Then, and this is the most important part, go to your Home folder (on Mac Only) and list the hidden folders with

```
ls -al
```

You will have two elements mentioning yarn :
.yarnrc.yml and .yarnrc

Type the following to remove them:

```
rm -rf .yarnrc
```

and

```
rm -rf .yarnrc.yml
```

Once done, go and make a brand new install of Yarn using npm or brew :

```
npm install - g yarn
```

or

```
brew install yarn
```

That should be it.

Comment: Good answer! this is perfect for those who jumped into the updated version thinking it would be an easy transition.

Comment: `npm install - g yarn` has a typo... should be `npm install -g yarn`

Answer (score 0):

RU sure you have yarn installed globally? Try `npm install yarn -g`. If you are a Windows user just download yarn from its website named .msi file.

Comment: yes it is. It installes globally but any yarn command after always returns the Error message mentioned above. "Cannot find module.. yarn-berry.js." Strange thing all my other apps work with yarn as tested. Anything newly (within the last 3 days) created with create-react-app doesn't work with yarn. :/

Comment: @user3281858 yes u should npx create-react-app and uninstall yarn and try npm install -g yarn@berry

Comment: @farukbigez I'm facing the exact issue. Running `npm install -g yarn@berry` yeilds the following error `Internal Error: The "yarn-path" option has been set...but the specified location doesn't exist (/home/[username]/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs).`

Answer (score 0):

After you run `yarn set version stable` and you add  `nodeLinker: node-modules` to the .yarnrc.yml file, you need to run `yarn install` again.

Then all the modules where found.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @amanteaux's answer, which is the best one here.

I wouldn't remove the entire .yarnrc.yml file as he suggested, because there may be other stuff in there you want to keep.   E.g, mine looks like this:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs
```

It's only the `yarnPath` line that needs to be removed.  If I were to remove the entire file than I'd get switched over to "pnp", which is the default for `nodeLinker`, and not what I want.

To speed that process up, I wrote (actually had ChatGPT write) a script to remove the `yarnPath` line from the .yarnrc.yml file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = '.yarnrc.yml';

// Read the file contents
const contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');

// Split the file contents into an array of lines
const lines = contents.split('\n');

// Find the index of the line starting with "yarnPath:"
const index = lines.findIndex(line => line.startsWith('yarnPath:'));

// If the line was found, remove it from the array of lines
if (index !== -1) {
  lines.splice(index, 1);
}

// Join the array of lines back into a string
const newContents = lines.join('\n');

// Write the modified contents back to the file
fs.writeFileSync(filename, newContents);
```

I then set up an npm script to call my node script in package.json like so:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "reset-yarn": "node ./scripts/reset-yarn-path.js && yarn set version berry"
  },
```

I can now call my script with `npm run reset-yarn`.   (Note: not `yarn reset-yarn` because your yarn install is stuffed up at this point!)